# JMeter - same request getting recorded multiple times

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I see a scenario, where a request is getting recorded multiple times via JMeter. When the same traffic is observed in Developer Tools, only a single request is shown up.

For e.g.

```
   In Developer Tools we see:
     
        Request-1
    Request-2
    Request-3
    Request-4
    Request-5
      
   JMeter after recording shows:
   
    Request-1
    Request-2
    Request-3
    Request-4
    Request-3
    Request-4
    Request-5
    Request-4
```

Not sure about this behavior. Am I missing something here?

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Ajith

I tried recording the scenario multiple times.

Components used while recording:

1. HTTP Request Defaults and set JMeter to:
   Download embedded resources
   Use concurrent pool of 6 threads
2. HTTP Cookie Manager
3. HTTP Cache Manager
4. HTTP Header Manager
5. HTTP Authorization Manager

Answer (score 0):

It might be either a bug in JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (especially if developer tools are open in the same session which you're recording) or your developer tools configuration doesn't assume "fresh" session and during recording the browser instance requests for the content which is in [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) or in [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or something like this.

1. Try re-recording the scenario in the [private mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history) so previous site visits won't impact the recording session. It would be also a good idea to tick `Disable Cache` box:

   [image]

   also check whether are any filters applied and if another browser instance is using the same JMeter proxy
2. Try recording using alternative approach like [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) and see which records are being recorded there. It's better to go for the same approach as for JMeter's proxy: clean session, no other extensions, etc.